# JAX-WS Filter monitoring tool

Tags: java, web-services, soap

Client/server application that communicates via SOAP is musch harder to handle exceptions than REST. I downloaded Manage Engine app for this purpose, but has a trial period for 30 days. I want this type of tool free and be able to write this exceptions in a log. Any ideas?

Comment: try "software like manage engine" in google, I saw some results there, like [15 Popular Sites Like Manageengine](http://www.moreofit.com/similar-to/www.manageengine.com/Top_10_Sites_Like_Manageengine/) or [Alternatives to ManageEngine Products?](http://community.spiceworks.com/topic/355378-alternatives-to-manageengine-products) or [openNMS-vs-ManageEngine-OpManager](http://network-management.findthebest.com/compare/4-6/openNMS-vs-ManageEngine-OpManager) or....